# SQL - How to join tables but keep all values for a particular attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I have two tables in ORACLE.

```
Table A

Date      Count
03.10.19  10
01.10.19  5
30.09.19  15
```

Table B

```
Date      Count
03.10.19  16
02.10.19  10
29.09.19  2
```

Is there a way to join them so I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Date      Table_A Count  Table_B Count 
 03.10.19  10             16
 02.10.19  0              10
 01.10.19  5              0
 30.09.19  15             0
 29.09.19  2              2
```

Comment: Was the last line meant to be `29.09.19  0 2` instead of `29.09.19  2 2` since `29.09.19` does not appear in `Table A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `COALESCE`. Try like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.DATE, b.DATE) Date
    ,COALESCE(a.Count, 0) Table_A_Count
    ,COALESCE(b.Count,0 ) Table_B_Count
FROM TableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.DATE = b.DATE
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c9ac525c95a53ba13f52d4bcfb24ba9)

Answer (score 0):

Both MySQL and Oracle support `USING`.  That slightly simplifies the query:

```
SELECT Date ,COALESCE(a.Count, 0) as Table_A_Count,
       COALESCE(b.Count,0 ) Table_B_Count
FROM TableA a FULL OUTER JOIN
     TableB b 
     USING (Date);
```